# golang 1.17 build failure [gcc failed: exit status 1]

Tags: go, gcc

ERROR:
/var/lib/jenkins/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.golang.GolangInstallation/go1.17/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-350634742/000048.o: unrecognized relocation (0x2a) in section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

FLAGS:
GO111MODULE = on

Command:

1. go mod vendor is working downloading all the dependencies
2. go install serviceName fails with the error above

GCC VERSION:
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)

Comment: Note that Go 1.17 is no longer supported.

Comment: With gcc you'd at least need the flag `CGO_ENABLED=1` as well

Answer (score 0):

Far as I see you are trying to use CGO for your build
Try Command This Command will tell the compiler to use CGO

```
CGO_ENABLED=1 go build
```

if you have custom compiler or if GO couldn't find the binary you can specify

```
CGO_ENABLED=1 CXX=g++ CC=gcc go build
```

if it is not worked out for you can customize the path or binary name of the compiler

```
CXX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc go build -x
```

if this answer still didn't work out a reply we could look into it again.